# Não consigo remover elemento da lista

Tags: javascript, java, html, arquivo, xhtml

Quando faço o upload das fotos usando `FileUpload` não consigo excluir da lista onde estou adicionando.

Uso esse `StremedContent` para ficar setando na lista `contentNova` toda vez que o método é chamado pelo `FileUpload`. O problema é quando excluo a foto some apenas do (``dataGrid) como mostra imagem abaixo, e não é decrementado da lista `contentNova`, com isso, nos métodos `salvarFotoNova()` e `criaArquivo()` são escrita na pasta do servidor todas fotos que existe na lista `contentNova` incluído as que tentei excluir.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu tentar excluir algumas dessas 3 imagens, ela vai sair dai, mais nao vai sair da lista onde estou adicionando(`contentNova`), e conseguintemente será salva na pasta do sistema quando o botao de salvar for clicado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como mostra nessa imagem, tentei excluir uma foto da imagem anterio, mais mesmo assim foi escrita na pasta.

**Xhtml**

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
 <p:outputLabel value="Foto Atual " style="font-size: 17px;" />
     <div class="row">
     <p:fileUpload  label="Anexar Foto" 
        fileUploadListener="#{ordemServicoMB.uploadNova}" auto="true"
        mode="advanced" sizeLimit="3145728" 
        multiple="true" update="gridfotosNova" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpg|png|JPG|bmp|jpeg)$/"  />   
     </div>
  <p:dataGrid id="gridfotosNova" value="#{ordemServicoMB.contentNova}" var="linfotosNova" columns="1" emptyMessage="">
     <p:column>
        <p:graphicImage value="#{linfotosNova.stream}" />
     </p:column>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     <p:column>
         <h:outputText  value="#{linfotosNova.name}"  />
     </p:column>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  </p:dataGrid>
```

**FotoMB.JAVA**

```
private List<StreamedContent> contentNova = new ArrayList<>();    
public void uploadNova(FileUploadEvent evento) {
try {

    contentNova.add(new DefaultStreamedContent(evento.getFile().getInputstream(), evento.getFile().getFileName()));

} catch (IOException erro) {
    erro.printStackTrace();
    FacesUtils.showMessage(3, "Falha em carregar imagem");
}
 }

 public void salvarFotoNova() {
    for (StreamedContent s : contentNova) {
        String nomeArquivo = s.getContentType();
        criaArquivo(nomeArquivo.getBytes(), nomeArquivo);
        }
}

 public void criaArquivo(byte[] bytes, String arquivo) {
try {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    fos = new FileOutputStream(arquivo);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    FacesUtils.showMessage(3, "Falha ao escrever imagem");
}
}
```

Comment: cara, não entendi nada do que você escreveu, revisa ai o seu post.

Comment: coloca um título mais descritivo para que outros colegas do StackOverflow também possam te ajudar